# We could set up there

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

This context comes from the TV show "*The Leftovers*".
It's a scene in which two men talk about a plan to kill wild dogs who are a danger to the town they live in.

A: *So I found another pack.*

B: *Of what?*

A: *Dogs. Couple dozen, I'd guess. I saw them slinking around the elementary school tonight. I'm pretty sure they're sleeping in a drainpipe. We could **set up** there and pick them off.*

Based on these definitions below It could mean that they are going to *erect some structure* there from which they are going to shoot at the dogs or they are going to *arrange the situation* of (shooting dogs) in some way. I'm not sure exactly what this could mean though.

set up

1. place or erect something in position.
   *"police set up a roadblock on Lower Thames Street"*
2. make the arrangements necessary for something.
   *"he asked if I would like him to set up a meeting with the president*"

(Both definition come from Oxford Languages Dictionary)

Comment: It could just be US regional dialect ('set' meaning 'sit').

Comment: I don't suppose the speaker gave his choice of verb much thought. Or more accurately, perhaps, the *scriptwriter*. It could just as well have been *"We could **go / be / wait** [up] there and pick them off"* without making any difference to the meaning.

Comment: Why the dislike for this post? I don't understand.

Comment: My downvote was because (as implied by my comment) I don't think *understanding the exact meaning of "set [up]" there* is significant in terms of understanding the overall meaning of what the guy is saying. And even if you made quite some effort, you might not be able to find any more instances of exactly the same verb usage with a similarly "vague" meaning. Thus it doesn't *really* represent a genuine obstacle to learning English, since you'll probably never need any better understanding that whatever you might have "guessed" from just *"We could XXXX up there and..."*

Comment: It's the same meaning as "set something up", but with an understood object you can omit the object. FumbleFingers seems to suggest it's vague or ill-thought, but I think it's perfectly normal for that sort of conversation and the meaning is clear to speaker and listener. (Although not for someone who hasn't been watching the show.)

Comment: @StuartF: I haven't been watching the show, obviously. But presumably the OP has, and *he* doesn't "understand" exactly what the text means, despite having cited two perfectly accurate / applicable dictionary definitions. Undoubtedly, ***set up*** tends to imply more than simply "go there". Specifically, it's likely that they will *position some "**equipment**" there* - but not necessarily - the usage would be perfectly natural even if all the speaker meant was *position **ourselves** there* (***along with our guns***, obviously, but they might just be in holsters, for all I know).

Comment: Please note: It depends on accent. Michael Harvey *could be right*. "We just set up on the porch and drunk our coffee". [country folk, which, a lot of people are in upstate NY] So, one has to actually hear it to know. And I think Fumble Fingers is wrong to say that it is not important to understand set up to understand what the guy means. "We can set up there." can refer to positioning yourself in a place with some kind of equipment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I just got a warning from another SE site claiming my comments were sarcastic and snarky...I wonder what they'd think of these. Anyway, I have to say that the idea of killing wild dog is pretty awful.

Comment: @Lambie: I doubt there's any point in advising the OP here to take into consideration whether the speaker had a "rustic" accent when trying to decide exactly what was meant. Most learners wouldn't be able to recognize Anglophone "country folk" by their accent anyway. And I maintain that if you really want to learn a language you should approach it the way you learned your mother tongue. You don't see children constantly looking things up to understand the *exact* meaning of ordinary spoken usages like this in their own language, where the *general* sense is contextually obvious.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think you are going too far. Learners are all different. And set up here is not obvious. Children hear things. Here, we cannot hear anything and intonation makes a huge difference in many cases. And if they don't recognize it, so what? That's one reason we're here. It is my feeling that you have been over harsh here.

Comment: I think there is a high chance that the dude might be from the south. He chews tobacco and carries a shotgun with him at all times. The subtitles say "set up" though not "sit up". Wouldn't that be a conclusive evidence that it's not an accent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it could mean either of those, or it could mean "position and arrange ourselves and our guns (and other equipment)

When you say "erect something".  It doesn't need to be a "building". It might just be a tripod or a gunsight.